# Twitter API and PHP in Rate Limits

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter

Ok so I'm having problems traversing through the objects, it's easy to do:

```
echo $user["ratelimit"]->rate_limit_context->access_token;
```

But I can't do the following:

```
echo $user["ratelimit"]->resources->lists->/lists/subscribers->limit;
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth($script["twitterck"], $script["twittercs"], $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
$user["ratelimit"] = $twitteroauth->get('application/rate_limit_status',array('resources' => 'account,application,blocks,direct_messages,favorites,followers,friends,friendships,geo,help,lists,saved_searches,search,statuses,trends,users'));
echo $user["ratelimit"]->resources->lists->/lists/subscribers->limit;
die();
```

And here's a sample response:

```
object(stdClass)#5(2){
    ["rate_limit_context"]=>object(stdClass)#6(1){
        ["access_token"]=>string(50)"311338379-795FzNCmmdre5VYjB066uPqXmT5jEwuC3DYoAGp8"
    }["resources"]=>object(stdClass)#7(16){
        ["lists"]=>object(stdClass)#8(10){
            ["/lists/subscribers"]=>object(stdClass)#9(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(180)["remaining"]=>int(180)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/memberships"]=>object(stdClass)#10(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(15)["remaining"]=>int(15)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/list"]=>object(stdClass)#11(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(15)["remaining"]=>int(15)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/ownerships"]=>object(stdClass)#12(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(15)["remaining"]=>int(15)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/subscriptions"]=>object(stdClass)#13(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(15)["remaining"]=>int(15)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/members"]=>object(stdClass)#14(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(180)["remaining"]=>int(180)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/subscribers/show"]=>object(stdClass)#15(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(15)["remaining"]=>int(15)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/statuses"]=>object(stdClass)#16(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(180)["remaining"]=>int(180)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/show"]=>object(stdClass)#17(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(15)["remaining"]=>int(15)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }["/lists/members/show"]=>object(stdClass)#18(3){
                ["limit"]=>int(15)["remaining"]=>int(15)["reset"]=>int(1378607278)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.